# fixed length structure with variable length reserved space

Tags: c, struct

In the embedded world we often have data structures that are passed around via fixed-length buffers.  These are relatively easy to handle using something like this:

```
#define TOTAL_BUFFER_LENGTH 4096
struct overlay {
    uint16_t field1;
    uint16_t field2;
    uint8_t  array1[ARY1_LEN];
};
static_assert(sizeof(struct overlay) <= TOTAL_BUFFER_LENGTH);

struct overlay* overlay = malloc(TOTAL_BUFFER_LENGTH);
```

That is, we use a data structure as an overlay to allow easy access to the part of the buffer that is currently being used.

We have a number of buffer formats, however, that also use the *last* few bytes of the buffer to store things like checksums.  We currently use constructions like this:

```
struct overlay {
    uint16_t field1;
    uint16_t field2;
    uint8_t  array1[ARY1_LEN];
    char     reserved[TOTAL_BUFFER_LENGTH -
                      sizeof(uint16_t) - sizeof(uint16_t) -
                      (sizeof(uint8_t) * ARY1_LEN) -
                      sizeof(uint32_t)];
    uint32_t crc;
};
```

As ugly as this looks for this simple data structure, it's an absolute monstrosity when the structure grows to have dozens of fields.  It's also a maintainability nightmare, as adding or removing a structure field means that the size calculation for `reserved` must be updated at the same time.

When the end of the structure only contains one item (like a checksum), then we sometimes use a helper function for reading/writing the value.  That keeps the data structure clean and maintainable, but it doesn't scale well when the end of the buffer has multiple fields.

It would help greatly if we could do something like this instead:

```
struct overlay {
    uint16_t field1;
    uint16_t field2;
    uint8_t  array1[ARY1_LEN];
    char     reserved[TOTAL_BUFFER_LENGTH -
                      offsetof(struct overlay, reserved) -
                      sizeof(uint32_t)];
    uint32_t crc;
};
```

Unfortunately, `offsetof` only works on complete object types and since this is in the middle of the definition of `struct overlay`, that type isn't yet complete.

Is there a cleaner, more maintainable way to do this sort of thing?  I essentially need a fixed-length structure with fields at the beginning and at the end, with the remaining space in the middle reserved/unused.

Comment: Why does the checksum have to go at the end?  Why not place it before the variable length part?  C99 has flexible array members, but those have to go at the end of the structure.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler We don't get to define the structure format, unfortunately.  These are buffers that we are receiving from external devices.  The checksums cover the entire buffer, not just the portion that's used (to better detect transmission errors).

Answer (score 4):

In your situation, I think I'd probably do things this way:

```
typedef struct overlay_head
{
    uint16_t field1;
    uint16_t field2;
    uint8_t  array1[ARY1_LEN];
} overlay_head;

typedef struct overlay_tail
{
    uint32_t crc;
} overlay_tail;

enum { OVERLAY_RSVD = TOTAL_BUFFER_LENGTH - sizeof(overlay_head)
                                          - sizeof(overlay_tail) };

typedef struct overlay
{
    overlay_head h;
    uint8_t      reserved[OVERLAY_RSVD];
    overlay_tail t;
} overlay;
```

You can then work almost as before, except that where you used to write `p->field1`
you now write `p->h.field1`, and where you used to write `p->crc` you now write `p->t.crc`.

Note that this handles arbitrarily large tail structures quite effectively, as long as the head and tail both fit inside the overall size.

Comment: That's slick!.. You separated the crc into a separate struct, then merge it back with the head in overlay.

Comment: That's definitely a more maintainable approach.  My main complaint with it is that the structure members are now grouped rather arbitrarily (instead of grouping by purpose/meaning).  There's an extra layer of notation whose only purpose is to work around the language's syntax.  That may very well be as close as we can get using straight C, though.

Answer (score 1):

You could define a structure that simply has the buffer with a CRC field at the end:

```
struct checked_buffer {
  char data[TOTAL_BUFFER_LENGTH - sizeof(uint32_t)];
  uint32_t crc;
};
```

and then place your "overlays" on its `data` field.  You're presumably already casting pointers to "convert" a raw buffer's `char*` into an `overlay*`, so it shouldn't be a big deal to cast from `overlay*` to `checked_buffer*` when you want to access the CRC field.

But if you want to have a field in a consistent position across a bunch of structures, it'd be easier to put it at the *beginning* of each structure.  That way you can declare it directly in each structure without needing to do anything strange, and you don't need any pointer casts to access it.

Comment: We do essentially that for simpler buffers that only have a crc at the end (except we wrap it up in a helper function).  For buffers that have multiple fields at the end, it's not quite as clean.  It also requires the use of two separate pointers to access a single buffer, which can be awkward.  It's definitely a step forward in the maintainability department, though.

Comment: If you want multiple fields at the end, you could define a `struct` for just those fields, and then a "container" struct with three fields:  the overlay structure at the beginning, some padding, and the crc-and-stuff structure at the end.  Since both of the inner structures are already defined, you can use `sizeof()` both of them to determine how much padding you need.

Answer (score 0):

How about that?

```
union a256
{
    struct
    {
        int field_a;
        int field_b;
        char name[16];
        // 
        int crcshadow;
    };

    struct
    {
        char buff[256-sizeof(int)];
        int crc;
    };
} ;

static_assert(offsetof(a256, crcshadow) < offsetof(a256, crc), "data too big");
```

The first struct contains data, the second define fixed size for this union.